# Unable to get the proper formatting of my PDF with jsPDF

Tags: angular, jspdf

I have Tried to export my data into PDF format but unable to get the proper format on my PDF when i download this file.

If i have only 2,3 fields then it's displaying properly but if i have more than 5,6 fields then, my PDF file is displaying like below.

[image]

How to fix this issue.

Is there any easy approach to export my data into PDF format.

this is my listuser.component.html

```
<div class="container" id="content" #content>                          
     <table class="table table-striped">
       <thead>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>User Name</th>
          <th>type</th>
          <th>Model Name</th>
          <th>Year</th>
      </thead>
        <tbody *ngIf="isTableResult ; else noTableResults">         
           <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
             <td>{{user.id}}</td>
             <td>{{user.username}}</td>
             <td>{{user.type}}</td>
             <td>{{user.modelname}}</td>
             <td>{{user.year}}</td>                                
          </tr>
        </tbody>
          <ng-template #noTableResults>
            <tr>
               <td> 
                 We are sorry , no users according to your search.
               </td>
            </tr>
         </ng-template>
     </table>        
</div>
    <br />
    <button (click)="downloadPDF()">Export to PDF</button>
```

this is my listuser.component.html

```
import { Component, ViewChild,ElementRef,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-listuser',
  templateUrl: './listuser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listuser.component.css'],
})
export class ListuserComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredUsers = this.users.slice();
    this._userService.getUsers().subscribe((users) => {
      this.users = users;          
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

  @ViewChild('content') content:ElementRef;
  public downloadPDF(){
    let doc=new jsPDF();
    let specialElementHandlers={
      '#editor':function(element,renderer){
        return true;
      }
    };
    let content=this.content.nativeElement;
    doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML,15,15 ,{
      'width':50,
      'elementHandlers':specialElementHandlers
    });

    doc.save('test.pdf');
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect your pdf to be printed?

Comment: with proper table formatting but it's not displaying properly on my pdf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not more idea on jsPDF as I have not used it more.

Here I have used a package named `pdfmake`. So, I have updated the answer using package `pdfmake`.

> Follow the below steps to add `pdfmake` into your angular project:

Install `pdfmake` using `npm`

```
npm i pdfmake
```

Then in the component add below lines on the top:

```
import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

Finally, add this much of code to create and download pdf:

```
function generatePDF() {
 var docDefinition = {
  content: [
    {
      layout: 'lightHorizontalLines', // optional
      table: {
        headerRows: 1,
        widths: ['auto', 'auto', 'auto'],

        body: [
          ['Name', 'DOB', 'Status'], // headers
          ['Surjeet Bhadauirya', '22/08/1994', 'active'] // data
          ['Preeti', '23/01/1995', 'active']
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};


this.users.forEach((user) => {
  let temp = [user.id, user.type, user.modelname, user.year, user.seating_capacity, user.milleage, user.pincode, user.number, user.email, user.cost];
  docDefinition.content[0].table.body.push(temp); 
});  

pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();
}
```

**Working Demo here:** [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcxlfw](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcxlfw?file=src/app/components/listuser/listuser.component.ts)